# Why in the implicit function theorem the dimension of the domain should be greater that the dimension of the image?

Tags: calculus, functions

When $f$ is a linear it is clear for me. Because $f^{-1}(0)$ is a nontrivial set if $f$ is not injective.

Comment: The domain and image of what? There are two different functions involved in the implicit function theorem, namely the function used to write down the equation being solved, and the solution to this equation. If you mean that the domain of the function used to write the equation has a higher dimension than the image of the solution, that's because the solution is essentially a surface embedded in a higher dimensional space. For instance $x^2+y^2=1$ describes a curve in the plane.

Comment: All the statement of this theorem that I saw start whit : Let $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\to\mathbb{R}^n.$ Why not $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$?

Comment: Oh. Here $n$ can be thought of as the number of equations; if the equations are "independent" then you will lose as many dimensions as you have equations. Thus if $m=0$ then you will get isolated points, which is not what the implicit function theorem is about. The hypotheses of the implicit function theorem are pretty much exactly the appropriate generalization of "independent equations" to the nonlinear case.